# Optimal Google Cloud Region with Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have to select a region for Google Cloud VM.

We tried to find the best region. We use Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1):

A map of cloudlflare's data centers is available [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/network/) with that information you can select a region which is in the same area as a cloudflare datacenter.

Altough I think it will make little difference.